# if(isset($_GET["cart"] == "delete"))

Tags: php

I'm getting an error when i'm trying to do this delete option.
Can someone help me out with this?
if(isset($_GET["cart"] :: "delete"))
When i'm trying to delete the cart item 
And the error is Syntax error unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Comment: it's just a syntex error. check all quotes, points, parenthesis, braces in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isset cannot be used on the result of an expression as you are trying to do here. Either use this instead of isset :

```
<?php
if(NULL!==($_GET['cart']=='delete')){
echo "not null";

}else{
echo "null";
}

?>
```

OR since you are just trying to see if the users clicked on the
   delete button try this:

```
 if (array_key_exists("cart", $_GET)) {



if($_GET['cart']=='delete'){
//your code for deleting
  }
}
```